Can't draw SVG in PDF with Apache FOP - Unknown formatting object "{}svg" encountered (a child of fo:instream-foreign-object}
I created the following code for a simple checkbox in a table using XSL-FO:
Java code
Element svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", "12pt");
svg.setAttribute("height", "12pt");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");

Element rect = document.createElement("rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", "2");
rect.setAttribute("y", "2");
rect.setAttribute("width", "20");
rect.setAttribute("height", "20");
rect.setAttribute("fill", "none");
rect.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
svg.appendChild(rect);

<fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" font-family="Arial" font-size="12pt" padding="2pt">
 <fo:block>
  <fo:inline>Checkbox: </fo:inline>
  <fo:inline>
   <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <svg height="12pt" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="12pt">
     <rect fill="none" height="20" stroke="black" width="20" x="2" y="2"/>
    </svg>
   </fo:instream-foreign-object>
  </fo:inline>
 </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>

However, when I try to convert it to PDF, I get the following warning: Unknown formatting object "{}svg" encountered (a child of fo:instream-foreign-object}
What could be causing this error?
I tried adding SVG properties to the configuration of FOP and using the fo:svg tag, but it still does not work properly.

Are you sure you shouldn't be using createElementNS rather than createElement?

@RobertLongson I will try thanks

Did you declare the SVG namespace in the FO document? From the snippet it looks like the SVG namespace is the primary namespace, but if it is stated like svg:xmlns="..." all elements in the SVG namespace should have svg:... in front of the element name. Or created with the createElementNS as @RobertLongson mentions.

Thanks, @chrwahl, for the idea with xmlns. Regarding svg:..., they should not have svg:... it's redundant. I fixed it by only adding xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg".

FOP needs to know the kind of XML you feed it. In this case there are two XML namespaces in play; the Formatting Objects http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format and the SVG http://www.w3.org/2000/svg.
There are different ways to declare the namespace. And you can see them in this example PDF. In the following example the SVG namespace is just declared in the svg element, and then FOP knows that all the children are of the same namespace (unless another namespace in declared).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <layout-master-set>
    <simple-page-master margin="10mm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" master-name="simple">
      <region-body region-name="simple-body" margin-bottom="20mm" margin-top="20mm" />
    </simple-page-master>
  </layout-master-set>
  <page-sequence master-reference="simple">
    <flow flow-name="simple-body">
      <block>Hello World!</block>
      <block>
        <instream-foreign-object>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="12pt" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="12pt">
            <rect fill="none" height="20" stroke="black" width="20" x="2" y="2"/>
          </svg>
        </instream-foreign-object>
      </block>
    </flow>
  </page-sequence>
</root>

In Java it is probably fine if you just use the createElementNS with the SVG namespace, and Java will find out how to declare the SVG namespace in the XML document.
As an XSL-FO example you add the namespace would be XSL http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform to the mix, either by letting the XSL or the FO namespace be the primary. In this case I think that it makes sense to have FO as the primary, because the output of the XSL Transformation is a FO document (with some SVG embedded in it).
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <layout-master-set>
        <simple-page-master margin="10mm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" master-name="simple">
          <region-body region-name="simple-body" margin-bottom="20mm" margin-top="20mm" />
        </simple-page-master>
      </layout-master-set>
      <page-sequence master-reference="simple">
        <flow flow-name="simple-body">
          <block>Hello World!</block>
          <block>
            <instream-foreign-object>
              <svg:svg height="12pt" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="12pt">
                <svg:rect fill="none" height="20" stroke="black" width="20" x="2" y="2"/>
              </svg:svg>
          </instream-foreign-object>
        </block>
      </flow>
    </page-sequence>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Thanks @chrwahl
Fixed it by simply adding xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg". That was enough.
Element svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", "12pt");
svg.setAttribute("height", "12pt");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");

